# Let $f(x) = [x], x \in [1,3]; \ \phi(x) = x , x \in [1,2]$ and $= 2x -2, x \in (2,3]$.show that $\int_1^3 f = \phi(3) - \phi (1)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $f(x) = [x], x \in [1,3];  \ \phi(x) = x , x \in [1,2]$ and  $= 2x -2, x \in (2,3]$. Then to show that $f$ is integrable and evaluating the value of $\int_1^3 f$.

I have done upto this. But there is a second part to the question:

Without evaluating the integral show that $\int_1^3 f = \phi(3) - \phi (1)$.

I am facing difficulty in this part. Help Needed!

Comment: Hint: Use the fundamental theorem of calculus.  There is a relationship between $f$ and $\phi$.

Comment: **hint** Try to draw the functions and you will se what you have to do.

Comment: **hint** try to evaluate the integral from1-2 and then 2-3.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Which is the derivative of $\phi$?

Answer (score 0):

$$
\phi'(x) =
\begin{cases}
1 & \mbox{for} & x \in [1,2) \\
2 & \mbox{for} & x \in (2, 3]
\end{cases}
=
\left. f(x) \right\vert_{[1,3]\setminus \{2 \}}
$$
Then use the fundamental theorem of calculus and note that difference in one point, here $x=2$, does not matter for the integral value.

Note: The derivative does not exist at $x=2$ because the left and right derivative disagree.

Comment: Actually, $\phi'(x)=1$ only for $x\in[1,2)$.

Comment: Thanks Hagen. I corrected it.